# How to have my site upload and link videos in users youtube accounts

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'd like to offer users the chance to share videos of their stories on my web app.

I'd prefer to have these videos posted in their YouTube accounts unless there is a great reason to have them in my apps account.  We'll need to moderate the videos with volunteers.

It seems like the simplest thing that could work is:

1) Have my Web App Link to the YouTube Phone App.  Maybe email a link so the interaction goes to their phone.

2) Have users make their Video using the YouTube phone app:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57407

3) In my web app, use YouTube OAuth to find their video and set metadata.

OR

3) Have users copy/paste video URL back into my Web App.  Maybe reply to the original email?

I'm concerned this UX is complicated.  Is there a way to automate these interactions?

What's the simplest thing that could work using the available APIs?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think this is yet available to Youtube API as the [sample upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) and [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) don't mention this yet. Try to file a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).

Comment: YouTube used to record from a webcam, but they discontinued the feature - maybe because it wasn't creating quality content.  Record from phone is available from the phone app.  Phone is better for my content - I'm looking to make a nice integration.